# GMSMapViewDelegate functions not called on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I have set implemented `GMSMapViewDelegate`, set it to self, and I still cannot get any of the delegate functions to work. The following is an example of my code:

```
class UserViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate {

    var mapView: GMSMapView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        if mapView == nil {
            mapView = GMSMapView()
        }

        mapView.delegate = self

    }

    func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didChangeCameraPosition position: GMSCameraPosition) {
        print(position)
    }

    func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, willMove gesture: Bool) {
        print(gesture)
    }

    func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, idleAtCameraPosition position: GMSCameraPosition) {
        print(position)
    }
```

None of the mapView functions are printing anything. I have checked the delegate and know it is set properly. Am I missing something?

Comment: I have not had any issues using the other aspects of Google Maps, such as setting locations and markers. It is only the Delegate functions I have been experiencing issues with.

Comment: Give your code where you wanna implement these , edit your post :) cant really help otherwise Read : - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: are you given the connection from your map view to current class

Answer (score 0):

So I thought that setting the delegate after
`if mapView == nil {
        mapView = GMSMapView()
    }`
    would be correct, but it's not. I had set the actual bounds in a later function with
`mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height), camera: camera)`
and once i placed `mapView.delegate = self` after that, it works!

Answer (score 0):

For me the fix was not setting delegate from storyboard connection inspector of UIView. even though I already set it through code but it was not working.

Go to Storyboard select your UIView and in Identity Inspector add Class name **GMSMapView**

[See Screeshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hX84.png)

Then click on connection inspector, in Outlet you will see delegate. Drag it to your view controller.

[see Screeshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eAM1.jpg)